# Is Property the right thing to apply in this condition?

Tags: python

I created a class

```
def __init__(self, label):
        self.label = (label)

def add_thing(self,category_type):
    if category_type == somthing or category_type == the other thing:
        self.category = category_type
```

But somewhere down the line there was a bug/error because I did this in some other function:

```
def foo():
    if hasattr(O - the Object created, 'the attribute'):
        do something nice to O.the attribute = gorgeous stuff
```

The add_thing was previously 'the attribute'

the problem is I've done this hasattr check in numerous functions.(lets say more than 2) where the check is on 'the attribute'. Naturally its not there so I would need to rename all of them to add_thing which is tedious.

I would like to know if its the property descriptor I should use somehow over all these functions to fix this situation or some other mechanism? (I dont know I have been trying to figure out how to apply property anyway but cant seem to find a proper example here)

Comment: Why not just Search and Replace in the editor?

Comment: @thefourtheye its like saying down the line some client uses the code while abstracted from class' methods and works on the other modules while Ive changed the original attribute, I should be telling him to search and replace.Im sure there's some better way to work on this

Comment: The proper way to do this, is to release the next version of the product, with this fix, to the client.

Comment: Please provide some *actual real world code*, or something close to it. What is `add_thing` / `the attribute` actually? Sounds a bit like you (knowingly or not) created a public API and released it. And while you made some design mistakes (repeating yourself by doing that check multiple times) that you need to fix, it's not clear if you can or should break API compatibility to push out a refactoring to fix this mistake, or need to fix it *and* provide some sort of backwards compatibility wrapper.